# Custom thread logic in Akka

Tags: scala, akka

I have a special code to execute when a pool thread start to execute and another when it finished.

I mean, A need to call an initialize() before a thread start to execute actors code, and a cleanup() after it, in order to initialize thread specific resources (Database connections as an example) and cleanup (Close any already open connection)

It will be great to do it in a thread scope. I'm thinking of doing in a trait with all actors mixing, but in this scope, the initialization is by actor. I think I'll have a better performance if I make it by thread.

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: The purpose of akka is that you shouldn't think about low level threading.  However, if you really want to do this I would structure your actor system with Actor A {handles your initialise and cleanup} and then spawns its own Actor Bs {workers to deal with everything else}.

Comment: Use pinned actors and thread-pool-executor for your pinned actors. Default dispatcher will share actors between threads.

Answer (score 0):

Especially for your cleanup code you will have trouble because there is no hook which you could use. I would recommend using the Actor life-cycle to model your resource life-cycle, i.e. create one DB connection when you start the actor and close it in postStop. Then instead of using a ThreadLocal database handle you send your DB queries to the (pool of) actors. Do not worry about threads yourself, that is Akka’s job.